# How to handle multiple annotations with same long and lat in MapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, mkmapview

I am dropping pins for contacts and some have the same longitude and latitude.  When the Pins are dropped on to the map they show up but when I touch once that has more than two contacts I only see the first and last.

So, what is the best way to handle multiple contacts at the same long and lat?

Ideally, I was thinking I could show a count of how many at the location and then I was hoping that the user could keep touching the pin and it would cycle through the annotations.  I am not sure how to do that, or if there is a better solution.

Thanks for any help or insight into the issue.

Comment: I have had this issue for quite sometime, haven't been able to fix it. Upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea:

[image: k-means]

Run the K-means algorithm (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5978803/412916) over the existing annotations and drop a cluster annotation when the pin density goes over an arbitrary number. If the user touches a pin you can add annotations and animate them coming from the cluster pin. I suggest you disable interaction while they animate because the logic gets messy.

Answer (score 0):

I would make one annotation represent an NSDictionary of all the contacts/objects at that latitude and longitude. Represent a multiple lat&long with a different color pin.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
//Code here to show red pin vs. blue pin
}
}
```

You'll need a custom init method for an MKPinAnnotationView subclass, something like:

```
-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinateC:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryParam;
```

Finally, to run a method on touching that pin, something like this:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
     if ([view.annotation class] == [NSDictionary class]) {
        NSLog(@"multiple");

// more code here to run a view for multiple contacts

    }
    else
    {
...
}
}
```