# MKMapView - Multiple MKAnnotationView With Same Coordinates

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have multiple `MKAnnotationView`s on a `MKMapView`.
Since all `MKAnnotationView`s have the same coordinates the user can't see them separately on the map and they all look like a single annotation.

How can I organise them on the map that they all be seen?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried putting different pin color to each pin?

Comment: @NikosM. They all have the same coordinates, only the very last added annotation will be seen

Comment: Isn't this what you are dealing with? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381203/multiple-annotations-mkannotationview-in-the-same-location-coordinates

Hope it helps!

Comment: @FabKremer Great Thanks, I've just implemented this and it works great!